Projections of isotypic modules onto invariant submodule
Let $A$ be a simple Artinian $\mathbb{R}$-algebra and $M$ be its minimal left ideal. Since $M$ is a simple left $A$-module, $D^{op}:=\text{End}_A(M)$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-division algebra by Schur's lemma. We also have $Ae \cong M$ and $eM \cong D$ for every primitive idempotent $e$ of $A$.
Let $\rho: A \to \text{End}_{\mathbb{R}}(M^n)$ be a linear representation of $A$. We know $\rho(e)$ is a projection of $M^n$ onto $D^n$ and $\text{End}_{\mathbb{R}}(M^n) \cong \text{Mat}_n(D) \cong \rho(e)\text{End}_{\mathbb{R}}(M^n) \rho(e)$. However, I want to know about the difference of $\text{End}_A(M^n)$ and $\rho(e)\text{End}_A(M^n)\rho(e)$.
Define $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}(M)=[M:\mathbb{R}]$, $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}(D)=[D:\mathbb{R}]$, and $\dim_D(M)=[M:D]=\frac{[M:\mathbb{R}]}{[D:\mathbb{R}]}$. I want to rigorously show if we identify  $\text{End}_{\mathbb{R}}(M^n)$ with $\text{Mat}_{n [M:\mathbb{R}]}(\mathbb{R})$, then $\rho(e)\text{End}_A(M^n)\rho(e)$ is identified with $\text{Mat}_{n [D:\mathbb{R}]}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes I_{[M:D]}$ which is a subalgebra of $\text{Mat}_{n[M:\mathbb{R}]}(\mathbb{R})$. How can I do that?
Is it even true or $U^{-1}\rho(e)\text{End}_A(M^n)\rho(e)U$ is identified with $\text{Mat}_{n [D:\mathbb{R}]}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes I_{[M:D]}$ for some permutation matrix $U$?
